# Is there an obvious database design for a bulletin board / forum?

Tags: sql, database, forum

Is there some kind of obvious database should I use for a Bulletin Board if I wanted to code one? I think I know how to code the rest of it, I know the imperative code to handle the logic, but I don't really know much about databases yet. This I can learn of course, I'm just wondering if there is something obvious I should know in the beginning, or an obvious place to start learning, besides sql 101. Also, please don't suggest reading the code of an open source project. I know that option is there. It's hard to decipher code in a language you don't understand really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this place they've got tons of database sample you can use to jumpstart a project http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/